# How to obtain a refreshToken using OAuth2Client (google-auth-library ) for a Google Workspace add-on application

Tags: node.js, oauth-2.0, google-workspace, refresh-token, google-api-nodejs-client

I have a Google Workspace add-on application built with Node.js with the following scopes:

```
"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.addons.execute",
"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.addons.execute",   
"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.readonly"
```

When the user gets prompted to accept scopes, I will get a list of tokens included;

```
userOAuthToken, systemIdToken, userIdToken
```

The issue here is that the userOAuthToken granted is time-bound, so I need a refresh token to access for later use. I am trying to access refresh token but getting an error:

> Error: No refresh token is set. at OAuth2Client.refreshTokenNoCache error.

I am using the following code to access the refresh token

```js
    const accessToken = req.body.authorizationEventObject.userOAuthToken;
       const auth = new OAuth2Client();
       auth.setCredentials({access_token: accessToken});
        auth.refreshAccessToken().then((token)=>{
        console.log("token is " + token);
      }).catch((err)=>{
        console.log(err);
      });
```

How can I fix this error?

Comment: No because the app built with nodejs does not have access to the built-in functions given by app script

Comment: Use proper tags in the future